# MainMenuViewController as a shared instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton, instance

Hello stackoverflowers

I have a dessing question.

I have a MainMenuViewController class. It has a method which shows a menu on the right side of the app. This method is called from different parts of the app, actually, in every navigation controller I have to set that method as a target of the nav bar right button.

Thats causing me to have code like this in every pushed view controller:

```
UIViewController *root = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[self.topBarMenuButton addTarget:((RecordsViewController*)root).mainMenuController action:@selector(launchMenu:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And also I have to give every root controller a reference to the main menu.

Which I dont like at all. What I´d like to have is something like:

```
[self.topBarMenuButton addTarget:[MainMenuController sharedInstance] action:@selector(launchMenu:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

So every view controller of the app would be able to access the main menu without having to get it from its root view controller or from the app delegate.

Is this a good idea? It sounds ok to me, but Im not sure if theres any disadvantage in the using of shared view controller instances.

Thanks and happy coding

Comment: i think a singelton as you suggested is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use singleton for your requirement.

In MainMenuViewController.m file

```
static MainMenuViewController *_sharedMySingleton;

+(MainMenuViewController *) sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized([MainMenuViewController class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
        {
            _sharedMySingleton = [[self alloc] init];

        }
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Where ever you want to access this object just call like this...

```
[self.topBarMenuButton addTarget:[MainMenuController sharedInstance] action:@selector(launchMenu:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```